# How to set a variable referring to the library database

Tags: vba, ms-access

Currently I'm working on a library database for all my Access apps which have common code and forms in it. It is going quite well, but the only thing I cannot discover is how to set a variable referring to the reference. The library name is set by a constant and at startup is checked if the file exists in the app folder and if this is equal to the path stored in the reference.

However, I want to refer to the library with a short variable "dbl", because I don't want to use the library name every time. This name might change as well. How do I set the variable to do this? I have tried         `Set dbl = Application.References(APP_LIB)`, and this is accepted as valid, but I cannot call any routine or form with this variable.

Thx!

Art.

```
Public Function CkLib()
'Needs to stay in the App Module!
    Dim ref As Reference
    Dim strLib As String

    On Error GoTo Err_Proc

    For Each ref In Application.References
        If ref.Name = APP_LIB Then
            strLib = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & ref.Name & "." & APP_LIB_TYPE
            If Dir(strLib, vbNormal) = "" Then  'File does not exist
                MsgBox "The app library " & APP_LIB & " is missing. Please reinstall the app or ask for support!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, APP_NAME & " App Error"
                DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveNone
            Else
                If ref.FullPath <> strLib Then 'Path needs to be updated
                    References.Remove ref
                    References.AddFromFile strLib
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next ref

    If Nz(strLib, "") = "" Then
        'Try to add ref
        If Dir(CurrentProject.Path & "\" & APP_LIB & "." & APP_LIB_TYPE, vbNormal) <> "" Then
            References.AddFromFile strLib
        Else
            MsgBox "Missing reference to app library " & APP_LIB & "! Please reinstall the app or ask for support!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, APP_NAME & " App Error"
            DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveNone
        End If
    End If

    Set dbl = Application.References(APP_LIB)

Exit_Proc:
    Exit Function

Err_Proc:
    Select Case Err.number
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error: " & Trim(Str(Err.number)) & vbCrLf & _
            "Desc: " & Err.description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Module: Mod_Generic" & vbCrLf & _
            "Function: CkLib", _
            vbCritical, "Error!"
    End Select
    Resume Exit_Proc
End Function
```

Comment: I've never used custom library but if it is selected in VBA Editor References (or added programmatically as you appear to do), why would you need an object variable any more than any other library Reference?

Comment: You say 'cannot call' - what happens (error message, wrong result, nothing)? Can't you just use the APP_LIB constant if need to prefix library elements?